# Who is the charmer in Socrates' dialogue in Phaedo?

Tags: death, socrates, souls

In Phaedo, Socrates was speaking to Cebes and Simmias saying that they are afraid of death that when the soul leaves the body, the wind will scatter her away (in their opinion). And later he says "Let the voice of the charmer be applied daily until you have charmed him away".

What does he mean by that ?

Comment: In your profile, do you mean *conversion* or *conversation*? I assume the latter.

Comment: @JoWehler, I meant conversion.

Comment: @JoWehler at the time creating my profile, I was only a member of Mi Yodeya community on stack exchange which is a Jewish site. This is why I didn't have to specify conversion to what, now you made me realize that I have to specify once I became a member of stack exchange outside Mi Yodeya

Answer (score 2):

The passage in question is *Plato: Phaedo 77,e8-9*.

The Greek text speaks about *ἐπᾴδειν*, which means *to exorcize by singing*. The Greek sentence has no explicit subject, it says *one has to exorcize*. The translator has added *the voice of the charmer*.